# Virtual inheritance constructor arguments

Tags: c++, c++17, virtual-inheritance

I know that virtual inheritance enters into the realm of "perhaps you should be doing something different," but I sometimes it is unavoidable.  I am a little confused about the preferred way to handle constructor arguments when using virtual inheritance to solve some sort of diamond problem.

Here is a very simple example to help me demonstrate:

```
#include <iostream>

class Ball {
public:
    auto diameter() const { return _diameter; }
    
protected:
    Ball(unsigned int diameter): _diameter(diameter) {}
    
private:
    unsigned int _diameter;
};

class ColoredBall : virtual public Ball {
public:
    enum class Color {
        RED,
        GREEN,
        BLUE
    };
    
    auto color() const { return _color; }
    
protected:
    ColoredBall(unsigned int diameter, Color color):
        Ball(diameter),
        _color(color)
    {
        
    }
    
private:
    Color _color;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const ColoredBall::Color& v) {
    switch(v) {
    case ColoredBall::Color::RED:
        os << "RED";
        break;
    case ColoredBall::Color::GREEN:
        os << "GREEN";
        break;
    case ColoredBall::Color::BLUE:
        os << "BLUE";
        break;
    }
    
    return os;
}

class BouncyBall : virtual public Ball {
public:
    auto bounciness() const { return _bounciness; }
    
protected:
    BouncyBall(unsigned int diameter, double bounciness):
        Ball(diameter),
        _bounciness(bounciness)
    {
        
    }
    
private:
    double _bounciness;
};

class MyBall : public ColoredBall, public BouncyBall {
public:
    MyBall():
        Ball(10),
        ColoredBall(20, Color::GREEN),
        BouncyBall(30, 5.5)
    {
        
    }
};

int main() {
    MyBall b;
    
    std::cout << "b.diameter() = " << b.diameter() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b.color() = " << b.color() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b.bounciness() = " << b.bounciness() << std::endl;
        
    return 0;
}
```

My base class `Ball`'s constructor requires a single argument used to initialize a member variable `diameter`.  Thus, every `Ball` subclass, has a `diameter` variable (yes, I know this could be accomplished using virtual method as well).

Next I have two subclasses of `Ball` (`ColoredBall` and `BouncyBall`) which both add their own member variables (they may also add some more features).  Here is where my confusion starts.  Since, for example, `ColoredBall` "is a" `Ball`, in order for its constructor to be complete, it must call the (non-default) constructor of `Ball` and thus must provide a diameter.  So, it seems logical  make this an argument of `ColoredBall`'s constructor as well and "forward" this along to Ball's constructor.  The same applies for `BouncyBall`.

Here's the "weirdness." If I now create a subclass `MyBall` which is both a `ColoredBall` and a `BouncyBall`, I need to explicitly call the constructor of `Ball` because `Ball` has been inherited virtually in both `ColoredBall` and `BouncyBall`.  It is this explicit call that really initializes the Ball class.  This means that, even though I have to pass the `diameter` parameter to both the `ColoredBall` and `BouncyBall` constructors, it is not used at all.  This means (as I show in my example), I could pass completely different values to these constructors and only the one passed explicitly to `Ball` will really matter.

While I understand why this happens, I am wondering if there is a better way to handle/express this?

**EDIT**
As an aside, for those familiar with Qt, I have this problem crop up quite a few times when dealing with QObjects.  Sometimes, I want to create a few interfaces (e.g., classes A and B) that rely on the Qt meta-object system, thus I inherit from QObject.  However, what if I want to create a class that inherits from both of these interfaces (e.e., class C), this is impossible.

Comment: Use interfaces to decorate your inherited classes.

Comment: Perhaps you could use one pair of constructors ? A public one that initializes virtual bases, and a protected one that default-initializes them.